# inputting all items of a list into an environment

Tags: latex

I have a list of names which I would like to input into a given  surrounding, e.g. a box. Put in a different way: I'd like LaTex to create a surrounding for every item in a given list.

Here's my list:
Frank, Fred, Fran

Here's my surrounding:

`\fbox{\name}`

`\name` does the following: it inputs the first item from the list and creates another \fbox for each successive item in the list until the end of the list, as a result outputting the same as (but saving the typing of)

`\fbox{Frank}
\fbox{Fred}
\fbox{Fran}`

I am thinking of the list of names as a "count" (redefining 1 as Frank, 2 as Fred...) and this might be the wrong approach.
I realise that a command can probably not do those two things at once.

If there's a simple solution to this: what is it called and where can I find it? searching for 'variables' or 'foreach' didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your application, you can either specify the list explicitly, or in a file:

1. As an explicit list (see [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764)):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{etoolbox}

   \newcommand{\printlist}[1]{%
     \begin{enumerate}
       \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item \fbox{##1}}%
       \docsvlist{#1}%
     \end{enumerate}%
   }

   \begin{document}

   \printlist{Frank, Fred, Fran}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. As a file in (say) `names.csv`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{filecontents}
   \begin{filecontents*}{names.csv}
   Frank
   Fred
   Fran
   \end{filecontents*}

   \usepackage{datatool}

   \newcommand{\printlist}[1]{%
     \DTLloaddb[noheader,keys=name]{namesdb}{#1}% Load names database file
     \begin{enumerate}
       \DTLforeach{namesdb}{\name=name}{\item \fbox{\name}}
     \end{enumerate}
   }

   \begin{document}

   \printlist{names.csv}

   \end{document}
   ```

In both instances, the output resembles:

[image]

Comment: for the second example, do I need both the filecontents environment AND the file?

Comment: @petz: No. filecontents allows you to create a file, that's all. The use of filecontents is just to make the example self contained. You can create the file in any environment you want outside of LaTeX.